# Relationship of the base resistor and the collector resistor in turning on / off a 12V load with 5V using a transistor

Tags: transistors, npn

I am testing a solution to turn on / off a 12V load (the load will be MOSFET for controlling DC Motor) using 5V input with a transistor (see attached file for the schematic and the test results). My questions are:

1. Why the solution seems working when VCC is +5V (the measured current are 7.3mA, 4.39mA when the LED is On);
2. Why the solution seems working but the measured current is quite low (1.36mA) when both R1 and R2 are 10K (when VCC is +12V)

[image]

Comment: Have you done all the math yet?

Comment: Please explain: (1) What is the difference between Input = 0V and Input = GND. They should be both the same. (2) If your first reading is correct and you get 2.3 mA emitter current when base is at 0V then you have a wiring error or a bad transistor. With no base current the transistor should be an open circuit.

Comment: @transistor - note the labels in his diagram- he has the meter as part of Re which wreaks havoc with his measurements.

Comment: @WHHUANG - A major problem is where your meter is connected. It should not be allowed to influence the circuit but connected where it is it acts as an emitter resistor. It appears to have significant resistance which hurts your results. | Move the meter to between Vcc and R2 and either adk\just Vcc until the top of R2 / bottom of meter is at 12V. | OR if you put a 1 Ohm resistor between 12V and R2 you will get 1 mV per mA across it. Put meter on mV range and use it to determine current. You can put a say 10\0 uF or more across the 1 Ohm but it hardly matters.

Comment: 0V means the input is floating (not connected to GND). GND means the input is connected to GND..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but is required to generate a temporary sample schematic. If you edit this question, then edit the schematic you can cut and paste the contents into a schematic in your original post. I will then delete this post.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFSBP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Normally we are interested in collector current as shown in (b) rather than emitter current (a) as the collector current is what we are trying to control.

Comment: +1 or helpfulness - even if temporary answer.